# Chart.js how to modify an existing legend

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How do I modify an existing legend in Chart.js?

I've seen complex methods of creating a custom HTML legend (using `generateLegend` or `legendCallback`), and a simple method of `options.legend.legendText` which should accept an array, but saw no change so assumed that was for version 1.

I'm looking to add text to the default legend:

```
type: 'doughnut',
data: {
    datasets: [{
        data: series,
    }],
    labels: labels,                
},
options: {
   legend: {
     legendText = labels.map((label, index) => `${label} - ${series[index]}%`);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Edit:***

I noticed that if the chart was redrawn (e.g. if the browser window is resized) the legend would lose the extra text.

I've modified the approach to work as an inline plugin so that the `label` object is modified before the legend is drawn.

```js
let labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  series = [4, 2, 1, 3],
  myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        data: series,
        backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange']
      }]
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    },
    plugins: [{
      afterLayout: function(chart) {
        let total = chart.data.datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => {
          return a + b;
        });
        chart.legend.legendItems.forEach(
          (label) => {
            let value = chart.data.datasets[0].data[label.index];

            label.text += ' - ' + (value / total * 100).toFixed(0) + '%'
            return label;
          }
        )
      }
    }]
  });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Chart.js 3.xx

I've included a sample for version 3.5 too.
You can alter the legend text by overriding the `generateLabels` method.

```js
let labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  series = [4, 2, 1, 3],
  myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        data: series,
        backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange']
      }]
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: "bottom",
        align: "center",
        fontFamily: "Arial",
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
          fontColor: "red",
          generateLabels(chart) {
            const data = chart.data;
            if (data.labels.length && data.datasets.length) {
              const {labels: {pointStyle}} = chart.legend.options;
  
              return data.labels.map((label, i) => {
                const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
                const style = meta.controller.getStyle(i);
                
                return {
                  text: 'This is ' + label + ' - ' + chart.data.datasets[0].data[i],
                  fillStyle: style.backgroundColor,
                  strokeStyle: style.borderColor,
                  lineWidth: style.borderWidth,
                  pointStyle: pointStyle,
                  hidden: !chart.getDataVisibility(i),
  
                  index: i
                };
              });
            }
            return [];
          }
        }
    }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```